# How to get a value of an input element with id contains special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML code:

```
<input id="lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_:services:dtServicesTable:0:_id68:0:framedRouteIp" name="lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_:services:dtServicesTable:0:_id68:0:framedRouteIp" value="10.9.9.9" class="" type="text">
```

JavaScript code:

```
var grade =  $('#lfr\\_\\_WSRP\\_e044d147\\_\\_55a7\\_\\_4e6b\\_\\_9e5f\\_\\_938e05d9050c\\_\\:services:dtServicesTable\\:'+i+'\\:\\_id68\\:'+j+'\\:framedRouteIp').val();
```

but my JavaScript code is not giving me the value.

Comment: <input id="lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_:services:dtServicesTable:0:_id68:0:framedRouteIp" name="lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_:services:dtServicesTable:0:_id68:0:framedRouteIp" value="10.9.9.9" class="" type="text">

Comment: underscore is not a special character

Comment: Please read this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value

Comment: Don't know from where you get this ID but as ID shouldn't carry any data, that's really wrong

Comment: You should seriously reconsider whatever it is you're trying to accomplish with an input ID like that.

Comment: thanks depperm , got desired output

Answer (score 1):

Should be like the following code since underscore `_` is not a special character, you have just one special character `:` that you have to escape.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var i=0,j=0;
var grade = $('#lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_\\:services\\:dtServicesTable\\:'+i+'\\:_id68\\:'+j+'\\:framedRouteIp').val();

$('#result').text(grade);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_:services:dtServicesTable:0:_id68:0:framedRouteIp" name="lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_:services:dtServicesTable:0:_id68:0:framedRouteIp" value="10.9.9.9" class="" type="text">
<br>
<span id='result'></span>
```

**Note :** Check comments in question *You should seriously reconsider whatever it is you're trying to accomplish with an input ID like that.*...

Answer (score 0):

You should only escape **:** as **_** is not a special character
So your javascript code will be :

```
var grade =  $('#lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_\\:services\\:dtServicesTable\\:0\\:_id68\\:0\\:framedRouteIp').val();
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

use \\ before : only as your Id have : special character   _ (underscore is not special character )

**Run below code and check output in console.**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var grade = $("#lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_\\:services\\:dtServicesTable\\:0\\:_id68\\:0\\:framedRouteIp").val();
        console.log(grade);
    });
</script>
<input id="lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_:services:dtServicesTable:0:_id68:0:framedRouteIp" name="lfr__WSRP_e044d147__55a7__4e6b__9e5f__938e05d9050c_:services:dtServicesTable:0:_id68:0:framedRouteIp" value="10.9.9.9" class="" type="text">
```